# What is the equivalent of WinForms Control.Invoke in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

What do i use instead of

```
Me.Invoke
```

when i use wpf?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be using Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)